# How do I revert to the original perspective on Eclipse for ADT?

Tags: eclipse, adt, perspective

I like the original perspective as installed for Eclipse for ADT. Unfortunately, I have really messed up the perspectives when trying to debug.How do I revert to the original perspective on Eclipse fro ADT ?

Thank you

CCH4ADT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Window and select the 'Reset Perspective' option. It will reset to your default perspective.